# Create all lowercase and uppercase letter combinations in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, iteration

My intention is to return all possible combinations of lower- and uppercase letters with variable length.

Example:
foo(3) would return all combinations from a-Z with the length of 3.

I know how to make a funtion which returns all with a fixed length, but you would have to change code to change the length.
How can I achieve this?
Thank you very much

Edit: Ive gotten it to work, my recursion had an error.
Here is the code to return a List of all combinations:

```
def test(charNumber, array):
    if charNumber == 0:
        arr2 = []
        for s in range(len(array)):
            #alp is an array with all characters I want to use, so I can easily
            #add characters if I want to
            for i in range(len(alp)):
                arr2.append(array[s] + alp[i])
        return arr2
    else:
        arr2 = []
        for s in range(len(array)):
           for i in range(len(alp)):
                arr2.append(array[s] + alp[i])
        return test(charNumber-1, arr2)

def prArr():
    print(test(3, ['']))
```

Note that that prints out one char more than value entered, and as you see you have to provide an Array with one empty string.

Output:
´´´
['aaaa', 'aaab', 'aaac', 'aaad', 'aaba', 'aabb', 'aabc', 'aabd', 'aaca', 'aacb', 'aacc', 'aacd', 'aada', 'aadb', 'aadc', 'aadd', 'abaa', 'abab', 'abac', 'abad', 'abba', 'abbb', 'abbc', 'abbd', 'abca', 'abcb', 'abcc', 'abcd', 'abda', 'abdb', 'abdc', 'abdd', 'acaa', 'acab', 'acac', 'acad', 'acba', 'acbb', 'acbc', 'acbd', 'acca', 'accb', 'accc', 'accd', 'acda', 'acdb', 'acdc', 'acdd', 'adaa', 'adab', 'adac', 'adad', 'adba', 'adbb', 'adbc', 'adbd', 'adca', 'adcb', 'adcc', 'adcd', 'adda', 'addb', 'addc', 'addd', 'baaa', 'baab', 'baac', 'baad', 'baba', 'babb', 'babc', 'babd', 'baca', 'bacb', 'bacc', 'bacd', 'bada', 'badb', 'badc', 'badd', 'bbaa', 'bbab', 'bbac', 'bbad', 'bbba', 'bbbb', 'bbbc', 'bbbd', 'bbca', 'bbcb', 'bbcc', 'bbcd', 'bbda', 'bbdb', 'bbdc', 'bbdd', 'bcaa', 'bcab', 'bcac', 'bcad', 'bcba', 'bcbb', 'bcbc', 'bcbd', 'bcca', 'bccb', 'bccc', 'bccd', 'bcda', 'bcdb', 'bcdc', 'bcdd', 'bdaa', 'bdab', 'bdac', 'bdad', 'bdba', 'bdbb', 'bdbc', 'bdbd', 'bdca', 'bdcb', 'bdcc', 'bdcd', 'bdda', 'bddb', 'bddc', 'bddd', 'caaa', 'caab', 'caac', 'caad', 'caba', 'cabb', 'cabc', 'cabd', 'caca', 'cacb', 'cacc', 'cacd', 'cada', 'cadb', 'cadc', 'cadd', 'cbaa', 'cbab', 'cbac', 'cbad', 'cbba', 'cbbb', 'cbbc', 'cbbd', 'cbca', 'cbcb', 'cbcc', 'cbcd', 'cbda', 'cbdb', 'cbdc', 'cbdd', 'ccaa', 'ccab', 'ccac', 'ccad', 'ccba', 'ccbb', 'ccbc', 'ccbd', 'ccca', 'cccb', 'cccc', 'cccd', 'ccda', 'ccdb', 'ccdc', 'ccdd', 'cdaa', 'cdab', 'cdac', 'cdad', 'cdba', 'cdbb', 'cdbc', 'cdbd', 'cdca', 'cdcb', 'cdcc', 'cdcd', 'cdda', 'cddb', 'cddc', 'cddd', 'daaa', 'daab', 'daac', 'daad', 'daba', 'dabb', 'dabc', 'dabd', 'daca', 'dacb', 'dacc', 'dacd', 'dada', 'dadb', 'dadc', 'dadd', 'dbaa', 'dbab', 'dbac', 'dbad', 'dbba', 'dbbb', 'dbbc', 'dbbd', 'dbca', 'dbcb', 'dbcc', 'dbcd', 'dbda', 'dbdb', 'dbdc', 'dbdd', 'dcaa', 'dcab', 'dcac', 'dcad', 'dcba', 'dcbb', 'dcbc', 'dcbd', 'dcca', 'dccb', 'dccc', 'dccd', 'dcda', 'dcdb', 'dcdc', 'dcdd', 'ddaa', 'ddab', 'ddac', 'ddad', 'ddba', 'ddbb', 'ddbc', 'ddbd', 'ddca', 'ddcb', 'ddcc', 'ddcd', 'ddda', 'dddb', 'dddc', 'dddd']
´´´

Comment: Can you post your fixed-length code?

Comment: So i now have it done with not fixed number.

Comment: were you looking for an answer at all? or did you intend to make a blog post?

Comment: I was indeed looking for the answer. Now that I have it I thought posting it here for future people who might have the same question.

Comment: I think future readers should refrain from using a function that is based on _if_ statements and 2 nested _for loops_ for a total of 15 lines, especially considering that it can be done using a one-liner module from the Python standard library, and that such a solution was even suggested more than 45 minutes before you decided to answer your own question

Comment: The problem is, as stated, that i want to perform a function on each result one after each other(bevore continuing to create the others ) which wouldn't be possible since the built-in module returns the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` and `ascii_letters` for that:

```
from itertools import combinations
from string import ascii_letters

for i in combinations(ascii_letters, 3):
    print(''.join(i))
```

```
abc
abd
abe
...
WXZ
WYZ
XYZ
```

Total length of this is 22,000+.

As a function:

```
def letter_combinations(n):
    return [''.join(i) for i in combinations(ascii_letters, n)]
```

If you also want `['aaa', 'aab', ...]` use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`.

Comment: Given the size of the output, you might also want to suggest a generator, like `yield from map(''.join, combinations(acii_letters, n))`.